# Exclude multiple test classes from running from command line

Tags: maven, maven-3

Is there a way to exclude multiple test classes from being run. On deployment server they are run (Just to say they cannot be deleted :) ). A possible way is to add `@Ignore` on test classes but during a commit i dont want it to go in accidentally. So command line option was a better choice.

```
 mvn package -Dtest=\!ATest test -DfailIfNoTests=false
```

At the end i have to build a ear which is also failing also i had to add `-DfailIfNoTests=false` for some reason. So is there a way to do it like :

```
 mvn package -Dtest=\!ATest, \!BTest test // something like this
```

Comment: Are those tests unit tests ? If so than they should always run otherwise those tests are integration tests and do not belong into the unit tests are which means they should be named different like *IT.java (see maven-failsafe-plugin) where you can use a profile activate/deactivate running integration tests...Furthermore you can defined things like [excludes on command line](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#excludesFile)..

Comment: thanks for reply. No they are DateTime test cases and are location specific. I saw the link you gave not clear enough for me, can you give a complete command though?

Comment: If thos DateTime test cases and if you need to turn them off manually than you need to fix your test cases....

Comment: That I have already done as I mentioned.

Comment: If you have fixed the tests why do you need to exclude them? Logically this does not makes sense..?

Comment: Can you please read my post fully please?